# Accent commands (e.g. \'e) don't work in a tabbing environments

Tags: accents, tabbing

How to write international accent like é or è in LaTeX? I've tried every possible combination using `\'e`, `\'{e}`, within `\textbf` or alone, but absolutely **nothing** works.
Below is the code I've tried

```
\documentclass{res}
\begin{document}
\begin{resume}
\section{EDUCATION \& CERTIFICATION}
\begin{tabbing}
\textbf{Imperial College}, London, UK \= \hspace{1.6in} \= Sep 2013 \\
Master in Economics \\[2ex]
\textbf{Ecole Sup\'erieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\bf{Ecole Sup\'erieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
Ecole Sup\'erieure, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\textbf{Ecole Sup\'{e}rieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\end{tabbing}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX doesn't process the accent and returns this:
[image: Processing of accent in LaTeX]

Is there anyway to write the letter é in LaTeX? If yes, can someone tell me how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Btw, we don't have the class `res`. Do you think you could redo your example TeX file using some standard class? It would help is in helping you ;)

Comment: @tohecz: See [`res` on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res).

Comment: Unfortunately, `\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` does not change anything

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is described in manuals to LaTeX that inside `tabbing` you have to use `\a'{e}` instead of `\'{e}`. This will work for you. As well, I recommend loading `lmodern` and `[T1]{fontenc}` to get proper accent placement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{EDUCATION \& CERTIFICATION}
\begin{tabbing}
\textbf{Imperial College}, London, UK \= \hspace{1.6in} \= Sep 2013 \\
Master in Economics \\[2ex]
\textbf{Ecole Sup\a'erieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\bf{Ecole Sup\a'erieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
Ecole Sup\a'erieure, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\textbf{Ecole Sup\a'{e}rieure}, Paris, France \> \> Sep 2012 \\
Master of Sciences\\[2ex]
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: less than a second quicker, but you get the +1 :-)

Comment: Thank you tohecz, `\a'{e}` was the answer. It's working now!

Comment: LaTeX is hard...glad I'm not the only one who sometimes gets confused on these things. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in order to simply have to type the accents. That means that you don't have to code `\a'{e}`, but that you can directly type `é`. I'm not sure whether this is very helpful or not, but in my opinion, this is a lot faster solution.